# Move data from one column to one of two others based on a fourth column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

So in Pandas I have the following dataframe

```
A B C D
0 X   
1 Y   
0 Y   
1 Y   
0 X
1 X
```

I want to move the value in A to either C or D depending on B. The output should be something like this;

```
A B C D
0 X 0 
1 Y   1 
0 Y   0
1 Y   1 
0 X 0
1 X 1
```

I've tried using multiple where statements like

```
df['C'] = np.where(str(df.B).find('X'), df.A, '')
df['D'] = np.where(str(df.B).find('Y'), df.A, '')
```

But that results in;

```
A B C D
0 X 0 0
1 Y 1 1 
0 Y 0 0
1 Y 1 1 
0 X 0 0
1 X 1 1
```

So I guess it's checking if the value exists in the column at all, which makes sense. Do I need to iterate row by row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont convert to `str` with `find`, because it return scalar and `0` is convert to `False` and another integers to `True`s:

```
print (str(df.B).find('X'))
5
```

Simpliest is compare values for boolean `Series`:

```
print (df.B == 'X')
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
Name: B, dtype: bool

df['C'] = np.where(df.B == 'X', df.A, '')
df['D'] = np.where(df.B == 'Y', df.A, '')
```

Another solution with [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) + [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df = df.assign(C=df.A.where(df.B == 'X', ''),
               D=df.A.where(df.B == 'Y', ''))
```

And if need check substrings use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df['C'] = np.where(df.B.str.contains('X'), df.A, '')
df['D'] = np.where(df.B.str.contains('Y'), df.A, '')
```

Or:

```
df['C'] = df.A.where(df.B.str.contains('X'), '')
df['D'] = df.A.where(df.B.str.contains('Y'), '')
```

All return:

```
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  0  X  0   
1  1  Y     1
2  0  Y     0
3  1  Y     1
4  0  X  0   
5  1  X  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using slice assignment

```
n = len(df)
f, u = pd.factorize(df.B.values)
a = np.empty((n, 2), dtype=object)
a.fill('')
a[np.arange(n), f] = df.A.values

df.loc[:, ['C', 'D']] = a

df

   A  B  C  D
0  0  X  0   
1  1  Y     1
2  0  Y     0
3  1  Y     1
4  0  X  0   
5  1  X  1
```

Comment: Hmmm, what if `str.contains` is necessary?